# filter to extract data from multiple lines using grok

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok, filebeat

i am new to logstash i am try to find pattern to extract data from this log messages where i enable the pattern in filebeat.yml to read from date to next occurence of date.

```
2018-05-21 14:49:12
Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.457 GHz  Access Point: 88:D7:F6:68:C1:78   
Bit Rate=144.4 Mb/s   Tx-Power=22 dBm   
Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
Power Management:on
link Quality=65/70  Signal level=-45 dBm  
Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:217   Missed beacon:0





    grok{
 timeout_millis => 60000
match=>["message", "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:mytimestamp}%{SPACE:ip}%{GREEDYDATA:val}%{SPACE:ip}%{GREEDYDATA:val}%{SPACE:ip}%{GREEDYDATA:val}%{SPACE:ip}%{GREEDYDATA:val}%{SPACE:ip}%{GREEDYDATA:val}%{SPACE:ip}%{GREEDYDATA:val}(?<powerlevel>(?<=Signal level\=).*?(\s))"]
}
```

this gives _groktimeout

```
filter {
    grok {
    match => ["message", "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:mytimestamp}",
       "message", "(?<powerlevel>(?<=Signal level\=).*?(\s))"]

    }
```

this gives only timestamp 
please can some one help me to fetch timestamp and signal level from this log

Comment: You only need timestamp and signal level?

Comment: @SufiyanGhori yes

Comment: i am able to get signal level and timestamp individually. since i need to create one event for the that entire i want to extract in single event to send elastic search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to match data between your date and Signal level as well. This can be done using `GREEDYDATA` pattern. Besides, you also need to match all the spaces and `\n` characters as well.

Have a look at the following,

```
%{YEAR}-%{MONTHNUM}-%{MONTHDAY} %{TIME}(?m)%{GREEDYDATA:irrelevant_data}Signal level=%{NUMBER:Signal level}
```

It will match both date and `Signal level`,

**output,**

```
{
  "YEAR": [
    [
      "2018"
    ]
  ],
  "MONTHNUM": [
    [
      "05"
    ]
  ],
  "MONTHDAY": [
    [
      "21"
    ]
  ],
  "TIME": [
    [
      "14:49:12"
    ]
  ],
  "HOUR": [
    [
      "14"
    ]
  ],
  "MINUTE": [
    [
      "49"
    ]
  ],
  "SECOND": [
    [
      "12"
    ]
  ],
  "irrelevant_data": [
    [
      "\nMode:Managed  Frequency:2.457 GHz  Access Point: 88:D7:F6:68:C1:78   \nBit Rate=144.4 Mb/s   Tx-Power=22 dBm   \nRetry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off\nPower Management:on\nlink Quality=65/70  "
    ]
  ],
  "Signal": [
    [
      "-45"
    ]
  ],
  "BASE10NUM": [
    [
      "-45"
    ]
  ]
}
```

Your grok filter will become,

```
filter {
    grok {
    match => ["message", "%{YEAR}-%{MONTHNUM}-%{MONTHDAY} %{TIME}(?m)%{GREEDYDATA:irrelevant_data}Signal level=%{NUMBER:Signal level}"]
  }
}
```

Comment: yes that works thanks, how to take out timestamp from that to by combing them?

Comment: yes i did it. can you please tel me how to get timestamp and parse to date field @sufiyan

Comment: you can use this, `%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:mytimestamp}(?m)%{GREEDYDATA:irrelevant_data}Signal level=%{NUMBER:Signal level}`

Comment: its use as multiline modifier, please have a look here, https://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html

Comment: what will be the syntax if i need to take multiple values from it @Sufiyan

Comment: @bhavya, the syntax would be the same. if you need further assistance with different problem please feel free to post a new question